# Collecting all words in a Trie in Java

Tags: java, data-structures, trie

I am trying to implement a method that will add all the words in the Trie to a List. I am using a Hashmap to store the character and reference node of the child node. Characters should include only letters a-z. This is my implementation of the node:

```
class Node {
    char c;
    HashMap<Character, Node> children = new HashMap<>();
    boolean isCompleteWord;

    public Node(char c){
        this.c = c;
        isCompleteWord = false;
    }
    public Node(){}
}
```

I'm not quite sure where to start with it, the leaf node will be able to tell me whether the word is complete, so I could traverse down the Trie till the leaf node is reached and append the characters to a string maybe, but once that word has been added how can I traverse through different branches of the trie to add other words?

Comment: What is a `Trie`?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie

Comment: Huh, so I've learned something new, thanks:)

Comment: One Q. you are allowed to store only az chars, nothing else even though your Trie might hold other chars?

Comment: The Trie will only be storing chars from a-z, validation is implemented in the insert method to ensure this

Answer (score 0):

First things first. You actually do not need to store a character attribute in your node class, since it is already implicitely stored in the `children` attribute of its parent node.
So your Node class can actually be:

```
class Node {
    HashMap<Character, Node> children = new HashMap<>();
    boolean isCompleteWord;

    public Node(){
        isCompleteWord = false;
    }
}
```

Also, like all rooted trees, your Trie will require a root. You will need a root before storing any word in your Trie.

```
root = new Node();
```

The root node represents the empty string, so if you need to store it, you will have to check the `isCompleteWord` attribute of `root`.

Then, to insert a word, say myWord, you need to start from your root, and apply the following rule:
- Consider the first letter myWord[0], say `'c'`. You need to distinguish 2 cases, whether root contains the key 'c', or not. If it does not contain the word, you will need to create a new node in your Trie. Otherwise, you just need to continue to 'walk' along branches.
- Once you arrive on the last letter, you will only need to set the attribute `isCompleteWord` to `true`. Here is a possible (totally untested) implementation of `addWord`, which adds a word in the Trie, and returns `true` if it was there already, `false` otherwise.

```
public bool addWord(Node node, String word, int idx){        
    if (idx == word.length() -1){ 
    // we're checking the last letter
        bool result = node.isCompleteWord;
        node.isCompleteWord = true;
        return result;
    } else {
        if (!node.children.containsKey(word.charAt(idx)){ 
        // no child with this letter, create one
            child = new Node()
            node.children.put(word.charAt(idx), child);
        } 
        return addWord(node.children(word.charAt(idx)), word, idx+1);
    }
}
```

To add a word, say `myWord`, in a Trie, you only have to call it as follows:

```
addWord(root, myWord, 0);
```

A function that checks if a word is stored in the trie is very similar to the one which adds words.

```
public bool containsWord(Node node, String word, int idx){        
    if (idx == word.length() -1){ 
        return node.isCompleteWord;
    } else {
        if (!node.children.containsKey(word.charAt(idx)){ 
        // no child with this letter, the word is not in the trie
            return false;
        } else {
            return containsWord(node.children(word.charAt(idx)), word, idx+1);
        }
    }
}
```